# In Asp.net MVC Razor Radiobutton, how to assign variable to name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have multiple radio button groups on my razor cshtml page.  I need to specify the name as a variable because each group needs to have it's own unique radio button choice.  Basically I have what is below that does not work.  that is, workshopDay does not appear to be being interpreted as a variable.

```
 @foreach (var workshopDay in new List<string> {"Wednesday", "Thursday"})
      ...
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(a => a.AngularUsignup.AttendeeParty, 
                new { @class = "radio",@name="@(workshopDay)" })
```

Comment: If you gave each button a different name, it would allow multiple buttons to be selected (so use radio buttons don't see appropriate). Also it you did override the name, it would not bind to your model on post back anyway.

Comment: I kept my example short to show my point.  My real case has 2 sets of radio buttons, each set acting like radio buttons and not checkboxes.  I do understand the difference between radio buttons and checkboxes but thanks for pointing it out anyhow.

Comment: Then you should indicate what you actually want to do. If you have 2 sets of radio buttons, you need 2 properties and if the value of those properties should be either "Wednesday" or "Thursday", then its `@Html.RadioButtonFor(a => a.AngularUsignup.AttendeeParty, workshopDay)`

Comment: It's been in the first 5 words of the problem description.

Comment: Yes, but what are those groups binding to? Trying to change the `name` attribute means you will not bind to anything, not to mention your not even giving the radio buttons values so nothing will post back.

Answer (score 0):

try following.

```
@foreach (var workshopDay in new List<string> {"Wednesday", "Thursday"})
      ...
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(a => a.AngularUsignup.AttendeeParty, 
                new { @class = "radio",@name=workshopDay.ToString() })
```

**Note**: As Stephen mentioned in comment to question it will allow all radio button to be selected. Instead you should use checkbox in such a scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those gotcha's:

To override the name attribute (or one of the other attributes that the HtmlHelper adds for you) you need to use the attribute name with the first letter upper-cased (so: "**N**ame" rather than "**n**ame"):

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(a => a.SomeProperty, new { Name="yourValuehere" })
```

So, I think your example goes to:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(a => a.AngularUsignup.AttendeeParty, 
            new { @class = "radio",@Name="@(workshopDay)" })
```

HTH